# Finding the indexPath of a cell with a gesture recogniser in handler method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pan gesture recogniser on a UITableViewCell which is attached to a method called `didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)`.

How can I use this method to determine which cell in a tableView this was activated from?

Comment: Could you please tell me why you have used UIPanGesture

Comment: The gesture's view is probably the cell depending on how you setup the gesture.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to add the gesture recognizer in the UITableViewCell subclass and also have a delegate property in that class as well. So in your subclass:

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegate {
    func cell(cell: MyCustomCell, didPan sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panGestureFired:")
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    func panGestureFired(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.cell(self, didPan: sender)
    }
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just assign you view controller as the cells delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your pan gesture to the UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Then extract the optional UITableViewCell and look up the indexPath in the tableView.

Make sure you setup the UITableView as an IBOutlet so you can get to it in didPan:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PanCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didPan:")
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        return cell
    }

    func didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // Sender will be the UITableViewCell
        guard let cell = sender.view as? UITableViewCell else {
            return
        }

        let indexPathForPan = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    }
```